# OpenGL, Rajawali messes up App interface/backgrounds

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, rajawali

I have a app with a Live wallpaper implemented which runs Rajawali. When implemented the live wallpaper within the app the layout/interface got messed up with black backgrounds and drawable not showing or showing white pixels, with the error code "GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501".

My guess is that the OpenGL messes with the app interface because it only happens when the live wallpaper is running.

This is the error code that I recieve:

```
04-07 15:51:11.757: W/Adreno-ES20(29982): <core_glUseProgram:1526>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
04-07 15:51:11.767: D/OpenGLRenderer(29982): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
04-07 15:51:11.767: E/OpenGLRenderer(29982):   GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

Anyone else suffering from the same issues???

how to solve it except removing the live wallpaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this thread:
http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/5889/androidhardwareacceleratedtruefalse

making sure no OpenGL operations are done outside the OpenGL thread fixed this issue for me.